# Adding ";" (semi-colon) in each space between hour and filename

Tags: text-processing, sed

Got here a list, as follows:

```
07:41 0840228.32P379995.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=307582,W=311813:2,
04:11 1574312.116821186.der472.netzwerk.com.br,S=301166,W=307582:2,
06:22 1540376.98P379995.der472.netzwerk.com.br,S=311813,W=312391:2,
03:39 8712441.254782468.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=307387,W=311615:2,
07:35 9841630.971395138.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=303039,W=303039:2,
01:16 2369857.123688174.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=298927,W=311615:2,
01:08 1845871.564387663.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=304067,W=305586:2,
08:07 1236913.325890982.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=299941,W=304067:2,
05:70 1086215.397447162.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=306747,W=309789:2,
06:41 9513575.225890982.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=305586,W=306747:2,
01:70 1965849.125749892.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=313423,W=309171:2,
09:12 9564136.687415393.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=309171,W=313423:2,
```

Anyway could be added a ";" (semi-colon) in each space between hour and file name, so that would result as follows?

```
07:41;0840228.32P379995.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=307582,W=311813:2,
04:11;1574312.116821186.der472.netzwerk.com.br,S=301166,W=307582:2,
06:22;1540376.98P379995.der472.netzwerk.com.br,S=311813,W=312391:2,
03:39;8712441.254782468.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=307387,W=311615:2,
07:35;9841630.971395138.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=303039,W=303039:2,
01:16;2369857.123688174.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=298927,W=311615:2,
01:08;1845871.564387663.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=304067,W=305586:2,
08:07;1236913.325890982.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=299941,W=304067:2,
05:70;1086215.397447162.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=306747,W=309789:2,
06:41;9513575.225890982.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=305586,W=306747:2,
01:70;1965849.125749892.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=313423,W=309171:2,
09:12;9564136.687415393.de472.netzwerk.com.br,S=309171,W=313423:2,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are no other space characters in your list, you can use `sed` to replace the first space character in each line with a semicolon:

```
sed 's/ /;/' file
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `awk` or `sed`:

```
awk '{print $1";"$2}' file

awk -F ' ' '{print $1,$2}' OFS=";" file

sed 's| |;|' file
```

The first `awk` command prints a `;` between the first and second column and the second converts the space delimiter to a `;`. The `sed` command simply replaces the space with a `;`. To edit the file in place with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's| |;|' file
```

With `awk`, assuming that the version is 4.1.0 or later:

```
awk -i inplace '{print $1";"$2}' file

awk -i inplace -F ' ' '{print $1,$2}' OFS=";" filename
```

Answer (score 4):

Had similar problem at an email server, just put this list in a `file01.txt` text file, then apply following command:

`cat file01.txt | sed 's/[ \t]/;/g' > file02.txt`

Comment: The `cat` really isn't required.  `<` works perfectly well, and sed understands additional arguments to be input files.